# APEX keeps creating debug messages even if debugging is turned off

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

My APEX application has disabled Debugging feature, but it creates debug messages when modal dialogs are submitted.

I tried also turn off debug messages running apex_debug.disable() as application process launched on new APEX session and disabling “Logging” feature, but with no effect. Errors and Ajax Callback requests are not logged. Just processing when modal dialog is submitted. Can you tell me how to disable those debug messages for good?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: "My APEX application has disabled Debugging feature" - does it mean that developer's toolbar (at the bottom of application, when you run it as a developer), has "No debug" option currently set? If so, hm, it means that there shouldn't be any debug info generated ... Was it, by any chance, created by some other developer?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this on apex.oracle.com ? I tried in my app. Created modal page with a "Close Dialog" page process, ran the page and clicked that button. No debug message visible in the debug dialog

Comment: On the other hand... how important is this in the grand scheme of things ? I realize it is annoying for you but is it worth putting any effort into it ? It has no performance issues and no one ever sees them but you.

Comment: Problem solved. Someone in called procedure put `apex_debug.enable()`. Sorry guys.